# how to listen aria-label text in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, accessibility, mantine

I am using aria-label html attribute for blind person. please help me about aria-label behavior in chrome. I am not able to listen aria-label text in chrome.

please guide me if i am on a wrong direction or am use wrong tool for aria-label.

Here is the accessibility tree:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<Box id="btn-english" aria-label="English" onClick={() => setLang('en-us')}> 
  <Image layout="fixed" height={65} width={123} src="/assets/english-button.svg" alt="Click here to select english language" /> 
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a screenreader is the best way to hear the [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name) of an element, such as the [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label). However, that assumes you are using `aria-label` correctly. You didn't post any code so I can't confirm whether you are using it correctly and if you'll hear it.

If you have a PC, then you can use the free [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) screen reader, which is very good.  [JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Downloads/JAWS) is another PC based screen reader and it has a 40 minute trial mode but otherwise requires a license.

If you have a Mac, then [VoiceOver](https://support.apple.com/guide/voiceover/welcome/mac) is built in. <kbd>cmd+f5</kbd> will turn it on/off.

Once you decide on the screen reader, depending on your platform (PC or Mac), then you'll want to search for some tutorials on how to use them. That's a separate topic.

**Update**

After seeing the code snippet, you still might not hear "English" announced by the screen reader. It depends what a <Box> element is. That's not a standard HTML element and you didn't say what framework/library you're using so I am not familiar with it.

An `aria-label` is well supported on interactive elements like buttons and links as well as landmarks like <nav>. See "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)"

Note that an `aria-label` will override any text for child elements (*) so the `alt` text on your <Image> (which is also not a standard HTML element) will be ignored. See [Warning #1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/#naming_with_aria-label)

(*) Child elements will be ignored if the containing element supports [naming from child content](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/#naming_with_child_content). Again, you're using a <Box> so I don't know if that qualifies as an element that supports naming from child content.

Comment: Good, 
I am using PC (Windows 10) and use aria-label like this
            <Box id="btn-english" aria-label="English" onClick={() => setLang('en-us')}>
              <Image
                layout="fixed"
                height={65}
                width={123}
                src="/assets/english-button.svg"
                alt="Click here to select english language"
              />
            </Box>

Comment: I moved your code example to your question.

Comment: I read your updated answer its very helpful for me. Sorry for incomplete information regrading question . I am using Box element which exist in mantine(4.2.2) library. My Problem solved by using NVDA .